# Google Console, Google Analytics, and Facebook show different install number?

Tags: android, facebook, google-analytics

In the Console, my app install is 41.
Google Analytics = 69.
Facebook Analytics = 140.

I'm so confused. Which one is the 'more' accurate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Google play store console shows the most accurate number of installs from play store. The only issue with console statistics is that the readings are delayed ranging from 2 days to even 6 days. So as in my case(attached picture) todays date is 9th April, but it shows reading till 5th April

[image]

Google analytic reading cannot be taken as 100% corrects as many crawlers/spiders may distort the stats.

Comment: That's too long. Also, I assumed that GA is more accurate since it's embedded into my code. TY anyway.

Comment: But what do you think of Facebook?